# extract variables from string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm using paperclip-av-transcoder gem to upload videos on my rails app. I also have the metadata field on my db as a string automatically genereated by the transcoder with the video information.
The string generated has the following format

```
{:length=>"0:16:31.52", :duration=>991.52, :fps=>29, :size=>"1152x720", :width=>1152, :height=>720, :aspect=>1.6, :audio_encode=>"aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D)", :audio_bitrate=>"44100 Hz", :audio_channels=>"stereo"}
```

I would like to get single data from this string like the duration and use it on my view. How can I extract the single variables from this string

many thanks

Comment: Do you mean instance variable ? You can also modify your question so we can understand you clearly. There are some many things one can infer from your question.

Answer (score 1):

If what you provided is a string then what you are looking for is either

```
h = your_string.to_h
h[:duration]
```

or

```
h = JSON.parse(your_string)
h[:duration]
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an hash. If you have this object in an `h` variable, you can retrieve the duration in this way

```
h[:duration]
```